# React-Native navigation jumps to wrong screen with useEffect and setTimeout

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack, settimeout, use-effect

I have a navigation stack with different screens that I wan't to render after each other. I set the timeout to be 5 seconds, so it will go to the next screen in the stack.

```
<Stack.Screen name="StoryScreenOne" component={StoryScreenOne} />
<Stack.Screen name="StoryScreenTwo" component={StoryScreenTwo} />
<Stack.Screen name="StoryScreenThree" component={StoryScreenThree} />
```

My timeout function is this

```
useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            props.navigation.navigate('StoryScreenTwo');
        }, 5000);
    });
```

The problem is that if I am at screen two and navigate back to screen one, the next screen that renders is screen three, not screen two as I want it to be.

Any tips for this?

Comment: Can you share more details? Also, when you navigate back to screen one, are you changing the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand when you arrive on the screen two there's an other `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
 props.navigation.navigate('StoryScreenThree');
        }, 5000);
    });
```

I think the setTimeout is still running so if you want to rerender screen 2 on goBack you need to use a clearTimeOut when you press the back button.
Look a this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals
But your first screen will not unmount when you go navigate so you need to use a listener to relaunch the `UseEffect`like this :

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile() {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      // Do something when the screen is focused

      return () => {
        // Do something when the screen is unfocused
        // Useful for cleanup functions
      };
    }, [])
  );

  return <ProfileContent />;
}
```

more info here : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/

Comment: You're welcome, can you accept my answer as solution to close the post ? Have a nice day.

Comment: (with the little V under the downvote arrow)